# jquery :contain multiple selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am facing some bad time while trying to select an anchor with content 'type' and 'size'.

I have a list:

```
<ul>
<li><a>type</a></li>
<li><a>size</a></li>
<li><a>size type</a></li>
<li><a>type</a></li>
<li><a>type size</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I need to do is to select all anchors with content "Type & Size"

I did select the anchors with content Type, I still need to concatenate the selection for more than once selction

```
$("li a:contains("type")").closest('li').css({"border","2px solid green"});
```

How can I do both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for both "type" and "size", you can add a second `:contains`:

```
$("li a:contains('type'):contains('size')").closest('li').css("border","2px solid green");
```

Two other issues with your code fixed above:

1. Also mind your quotes. If the string is using `"`, use `'` within it.
2. You had `{` and `}`, but you weren't giving a valid object initializer. For the above, you don't need an object, just two arguments. But if you were using an object (which is also valid), you'd need a `:` between the property name and value, e.g `{"border": "2px solid green"}`.

**Live Example:**

```js
$("li a:contains('type'):contains('size')").closest('li').css("border","2px solid green");
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>This has type</a></li>
  <li><a>This has size</a></li>
  <li><a>This has type and size</a></li>
  <li><a>This has neither</a></li>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```